# Need 50Hz detection antenna for reception of AC mains signal

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, antennas, radio

Anyone know how can i design antenna for electric field detection. i m trying to make contactless Ac mains Detector which range is near about 1-mtr long.
my question is about possibility of antenna construction for electric field sensor. but as i calculate the wavelength (for 50hz) is around 6*10^6km its mean the antenna height (lambda/4) is equal to 1500km long. so this is very difficult to construct. i need some pcb mounted antenna for that. is anyone have an idea please help me out.

Comment: If your calculations are causing errors, you could show them here and we can look at that.

Comment: no sir i m not doing any calculation till now. bcoz i have no idea how to start from beginning. i have an idea only about calculation of  microstrip patch antenna @Dr jh

Comment: If you are doing a calculation (as in your question you stated _but as i calculate the wavelength (for 50hz) is around 6*10^6km its mean the antenna height (lambda/4) is equal to 1500km long_) ....a six billion  meter wavelength seems a bit off don’t you think?

Comment: just can tell me how do i start for calculation

Comment: which type of antenna is best for this application

Answer (score 1):

this can be easily done by making your "antenna" in the form of a loop consisting of many turns of wire, surrounding the AC mains line. This *coil* then becomes the *secondary winding* of a transformer in which the AC mains line is the *primary*. For this to work, only the HOT line of the two-wire AC mains should go through the loop- NOT both of the lines, and a load (like a small heater, etc.) must be connected to the AC mains, so that current will be flowing.

You can buy a tool called a *clip-on ammeter probe* which is a miniature version of what I have just described. You then connect the output plug of the clip-on probe to the input of an oscilloscope, on which you can monitor the mains signal.

Comment: thank you sir @niels nielsen